# Circuit breaker problem with well and house

Tags: electrical

So everytime we have a power outage and have to run our generator, I turn our main off and start the generator, when I turn the breaker to the well off after it fills the house to save gas on the generator it also shuts off certain areas of the house, even though it has its own breaker. Any ideas as to what is happing. It's been doing this more and more everytime we have to use the generator. I've check the breakers, there not loose or burnt looking.

Comment: Do you leave the generator running to power the rest of the house after the well pump shuts off?   If so, there would be no reason to turn off the breaker to the well pump, since the pressure switch would have done that.   You may have some wonky wiring where the well pump is on the same circuit as other parts of the house.  You may also have issues with AFCI or GFIC breakers that are very sensitive. If the circuits that cut out have "test" buttons on them in the panel, there's your clue. Probably time to bring in a pro, as much as I ALWAYS hate to say this here.

Comment: What happens if you turn the well breaker off while the house is on utility power?

Comment: When there's power to the house everything runs great. I have noticed that the main breaker is getting weak. The breakers haven't been changed since I've been here. The last time I use the generator I had no issue. This time if I turn the well breaker on the pump points stay on so I do t want to burn up the well pump. So I shut it off and it turned other parts of the house off and some of those parts of the house are on different breakers

Comment: We have the old style breakers made in the 70s

Comment: We would need to know more about your wiring, in particular how the generator ties in, and especially the generator interlock (the linkage that keeps you from back-feeding the grid).  Photos are good. To add them, [edit] the question.  Note that you either a) must use the same browser you used to ask the question, or b) register the account and sign in on the other browser/device.